# How to list a process tree on Windows?

Tags: windows, process, ps

I know in Linux it's very useful the `pstree` command and something like that is what I'm looking for... but how to make a detailed process list (tree) on Windows terminal?

Comment: have you tried with `top` or `ps auxf` maybe it's not what you're looking for, but combined with `pstree` you should get the information, if it's worth it to you, please let me know to make this an answer!!

Comment: oh, sorry I just read you're on windows...there is an app called `process monitor` that should do the trick...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use a program called [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). This program allows you to do what you want.

> Process Monitor is an advanced monitoring tool for Windows that shows real-time file system, Registry and process/thread activity. It combines the features of two legacy Sysinternals utilities, Filemon and Regmon, and adds an extensive list of enhancements including rich and non-destructive filtering, comprehensive event properties such session IDs and user names, reliable process information, full thread stacks with integrated symbol support for each operation, simultaneous logging to a file, and much more. Its uniquely powerful features will make Process Monitor a core utility in your system troubleshooting and malware hunting toolkit.

It also provides exactly what you want:

> Process tree tool shows relationship of all processes referenced in a trace.

Answer (score 8):

Use `pslist64.exe -t` from [SysInternals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals).

Comment: This is useful for generating a list of processes on the command line that can be saved to a file or processed as text.

Comment: As the OP asked for a command line tool, I guess this is the most appropriate answer. And also exactly what I was looking for when connecting to a remote Windows server via SSH to quickly see what processes are currently running.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Process Exporer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) from Sysinternals. It is like an advanced task manager, there is a tree view as well.

Comment: I was going to post this as an answer but you were here already so upvoted. I find the interface of *Process Explorer* to be more usable than *Process Monitor* for navigating the tree of processes.

Answer (score 0):

This powershell cmdlet `Print-ProcessTree` will list a primitive process tree.

```powershell
function Print-ProcessTree() {

    function Get-ProcessAndChildProcesses($Level, $Process) {
        "{0}[{1,-5}] [{2}]" -f ("  " * $Level), $Process.ProcessId, $Process.Name
        $Children = $AllProcesses | where-object {$_.ParentProcessId -eq $Process.ProcessId -and $_.CreationDate -ge $Process.CreationDate}
        if ($null -ne $Children) {
            foreach ($Child in $Children) {
                Get-ProcessAndChildProcesses ($Level + 1) $Child
            }
        }
    }

    $AllProcesses = Get-CimInstance -ClassName "win32_process"
    $RootProcesses = @()
    # Process "System Idle Process" is processed differently, as ProcessId and ParentProcessId are 0
    # $AllProcesses is sliced from index 1 to the end of the array
    foreach ($Process in $AllProcesses[1..($AllProcesses.length-1)]) {
        $Parent = $AllProcesses | where-object {$_.ProcessId -eq $Process.ParentProcessId -and $_.CreationDate -lt $Process.CreationDate}
        if ($null -eq $Parent) {
            $RootProcesses += $Process
        }
    }
    # Process the "System Idle process" separately
    "[{0,-5}] [{1}]" -f $AllProcesses[0].ProcessId, $AllProcesses[0].Name
    foreach ($Process in $RootProcesses) {
        Get-ProcessAndChildProcesses 0 $Process
    }
}
```

Modified from [actualadmins.nl](https://actualadmins.nl/powershell_get_an_indented_process_tree/).